# Como somar atributo em array JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
[{"descricao": "teste",
"January": "2454.00",
"February": "220.00",
"March": "1070.25"}, {
"descricao": "teste2",
"January": "275.00"}, {
"descricao": "teste3",
"January": "275.00"}]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso gravar numa variável o somatório dos meses:

1. January: total
2. February: total
3. March: total

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de percorrer essa array e ir somando os numeros (convertendo essas string para *Number*) e, por exemplo criando um objeto com o resultado:

```js
var dados = [{
  "descricao": "teste",
  "January": "2454.00",
  "February": "220.00",
  "March": "1070.25"
}, {
  "descricao": "teste2",
  "January": "275.00"
}, {
  "descricao": "teste3",
  "January": "275.00"
}];
var somador = {};
dados.forEach(function(dado) {
  Object.keys(dado).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (prop == 'descricao') return;
    if (!somador[prop]) somador[prop] = 0;
    somador[prop] += Number(dado[prop]);
  });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(somador, 4, '\t'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito diferente:

```js
var json = [{"descricao": "teste",
"January": "2454.00",
"February": "220.00",
"March": "1070.25"}, {
"descricao": "teste2",
"January": "275.00"}, {
"descricao": "teste3",
"January": "275.00"}];

var total = {
  "January": 0,
  "February": 0,
  "March": 0
};

for(j in json) {
   total['January'] += Number(json[j]['January']) | 0;
   total['February'] += Number(json[j]['February']) | 0;
   total['March'] += Number(json[j]['March']) | 0;
}

console.log(total);
```